# Парсинг. Сбор информации с одинаковыми тегами

Tags: python, парсер, теги

Как спарсить значение тегов `span class="section__info` по отдельности?

Я пробовал собрать подобную "елку":

```py
adress = soup.find("div", class_="row blockInfo").find("div", class_="col").find(class_="blockInfo__section section").find(class_="section__info").get_text(strip=True)
```

Но проблема в том, что команда `find` собирает только первое значение. Пробовал рядом с `find(class_="section__info")` ставить `[1]`, `[2]` и тд - выдает ошибку. Не могли бы подсказать, что нужно сделать.

```html
<div class="row blockInfo">
  <div class="col">
      <h2 class="blockInfo__title">Общая информация о доставке</h2>
      <section class="blockInfo__section section">
          <span class="section__title">Способ доставки</span>
          <span class="section__info">Автомобиль</span>
      </section> 
      <section class="blockInfo__section section">
          <span class="section__title">Заказчик</span>
          <span class="section__info">ООО "Элеком"</span>
      </section> 
      <section class="blockInfo__section section">
          <span class="section__title">Адрес</span>
          <span class="section__info">Москва"</span>
      </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сразу спарсить все `span` с классом `section__info` при помощи функции `findAll`. Как раз она находит не первый попавшийся подходящий элемент, а все и возвращает их в виде массива.

Далее нужно просто у каждого элемента получить текст.

Вот пример кода:

```py
adress = [s.get_text(strip=True) for s in soup.findAll("span", class_="section__info")]
print(adress)
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
['Автомобиль', 'ООО "Элеком"', 'Москва"']
```